# Cant run any commands - -bash: ls: command not found

Tags: command-line, bashrc

I am logged into a remote shell and I had root access to this. I was trying to edit my `.bashrc` and `.bashrc_profiles` files when suddenly my connection snapped, leaving the files open. I suspect something went wrong. How can I restore these files from the command line?

I tried copying from `/etc/skel`, however my `cp` command is also not working. Neither do `nano` or `vim` work.

Comment: Did you try with `/bin/cp ...`? Your `$PATH` variable might be not set correctly due your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you broke your `$PATH`. That's easy to fix though, you can still use the full path to a command. So, for example, to get the default `.bashrc` back, you can do:

```
/bin/cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/
```

Same for `nano` and `vim`, just use `/bin/nano` and `/usr/bin/vim`. Finally, note that there's no such thing as `.bashrc_profiles`. There is `~/.profile`, `~/.bash_profile` (if this file exists, `~/.profile` is ignored by bash), and `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Thanks terdon, I will try this. I had mistakenly typed it wrong - A bit of a lazy weekend. Cheers! :)

Comment: I executed /bin/cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/ but no effect, is there anything to be done to refresh and propagate these changes?

Comment: @User3 the PATH is usually set in `~/.profile`. So, to revert everything back to default, run `/bin/cp /etc/skel/.{bashrc,profile,bash_profile} ~/`. Then log out and log back in.

Comment: logged out and in again, everything restored. Thanks a ton bud :)

Comment: However for others who might stumble here, I had messed up the enviornments file in etc. I cleared that and all was good!